# Visual Studio Code e React

Tags: visual-studio-code, react

Comecei há pouco tempo estudar ReactJS e de início escolhi o VS Code como ferramenta para desenvolvimento,porém tá acontecendo algo bizarro que não ajuda nada no desenvolvimento. Toda vez que preciso salvar alguma coisa no código para as alterações surtirem efeito,simplesmente o código fica bagunçado,tags fora de ordem enfim vira uma bagunça. Utilizo o "Ctrl + S" e acontece isso. Gostaria de soluções e se passaram por isso.

Comment: Eu uso VSCode com ReactJs tb e nunca aconteceu comigo. Sugiro reinstalar e mudar a versão do VSCode, se está na ultima voltar uma ou avançar uma..

Comment: Você deve ter algum plugin de autoformatação instalado. Verifique todos os plugins que estão ativos.

Comment: Concordo com o LINQ provavelmente vc instalou algum Plugin que está bagunçando seu código! Ou então c mudou alguma config nativa de Tabs no Json... tipo `"[javascript]": { "editor.tabSize": 2, "editor.insertSpaces": false, "editor.detectIndentation": false }`